# Can someone explain why I am getting a segmentation error when I run my Python Code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, segmentation-fault

I am running Python3.9.7 on a MacBook Pro m1 running OS Ventura 13.3

Everytime I try to run the following code, I run into:
`zsh: segmentation fault  python3 INLIST_CREATOR.py`

The order of implementation is:

1. A new tkinter window asks for user input for a new file name.
2. A new file with the input name is created.
3. A new tkinter window opens with different options. Each option opens a new tkinter (one at a time) window that takes in specific inputs and appends them to the new text file.

Problem:
Step 1),2) goes alright. The problem arises when I try to use the options. If I use the "Add Stellar Model" option the aforementioned error comes. (The problem is between line 12 to 23)

Attempted Solutions:
Tried to reinstall tkinter but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you very much.
Aayush Desai

EDIT: PFA the shorter version that recreates the same error.
CODE:

```
    #make tkinter window to create a new text file
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np


class editStellarModel():
    def __init__(self):
        self.stellar_model = {'model_type':''}
        self.fname = fname


    def take_stellar_model_input(self):
        roots = Tk()
        self.roots = roots
        self.roots.title('Add stellar model')
        self.roots.geometry('300x800')
        Label(self.roots,text="model_type =").place(x=0,y=0)
        self.options_modeltype = ['\'HOM\'','\'POLY\'','\'EVOL\'']
        self.clicked_options_modeltype = StringVar(self.roots)
        self.clicked_options_modeltype.set(self.options_modeltype[0])
        self.drop_options_modeltype = OptionMenu(self.roots,self.clicked_options_modeltype, *self.options_modeltype)
        self.stellar_model['model_type'] = self.clicked_options_modeltype
        self.drop_options_modeltype.place(x=100,y=0)
        

    def add_stellar_model_to_file(self):
        keylist = list(self.stellar_model.keys())
        file = open(self.fname, 'a')
        file.write(f'\n&model\n')
        file.close()
        for i in keylist:
            if(self.stellar_model[i].get() != ''):
                key = i
                print(i,self.stellar_model[i])
                if(self.stellar_model[i].get() == 'NONE'):
                    continue
                file = open(self.fname, 'a')
                file.write(f'  {i} = {self.stellar_model[key].get()}\n') 
                file.close()
        file = open(self.fname, 'a')
        file.write(f'/\n')
        file.close()
        self.roots.destroy()
    
def find_active_tags(fname):
    active_tags = []
    count = 0
    with open(fname) as file:
        for item in file:
            if item.startswith('  tag'):
                count+=1
                active_tags.append(item.split('=')[1].strip())
    if count == 0:
        active_tags.append('')
    return active_tags
class create_file:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fname = ''
    def make_file(self):
        root = Tk()
        root.title('Create new file')
        root.geometry('200x70')
        self.root = root
        Label(self.root,text="File Name").place(x=0,y=0)
        self.fnames = Entry(self.root)
        self.fnames.place(x=70,y=0)
        button = Button(root, text='Create File', command=self.actually_make_file)
        button.place(x=100,y=30)  
        self.root.mainloop()
    def actually_make_file(self):
        file = open(self.fnames.get(), 'w')
        file.close()
        self.fname = self.fnames.get()
        self.root.destroy()

efile = create_file()
efile.make_file()
fname = efile.fname

root = Tk()
root.title('Edit said file')
root.geometry('300x500')
estellar = editStellarModel()

button = Button(root, text='Add Stellar Model', command=estellar.take_stellar_model_input)
button.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

UPDATE: When I try run the same code in a Jupyter notebook, the segmentation fault seems to disappear and I can use all the menus, in any order.

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [mre] - this is a lot of code to sift through. If you already know where the affected lines are, I suggest starting there and working backwards. If you're getting an error, please [edit] your question to include the traceback text.

Comment: Why are you using duplicated `roots = Tk(`)? Using one tk() will do entirely script.

Comment: I duplicated them because I wanted to destroy the window once the button in that window was pressed.

Comment: In `makefile` function should be `root = Toplevel()`

Comment: Thank you @toyotaSupra. I tried that, but it still doesnt solve the segmentation fault I get when selecting the model type.

Comment: Your code is working. But I noticed that you're using mac.

Comment: Yes, I tried it on a linux machine as well and seems to work. Just seems to crash on macos.